# Working with Queried Results in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model that ends with:

```
def __str__(self): #python 3.3. is __str__
    a = str(self.name) +'<br>' + str(self.phone)+'<br>'+ str(self.email)
    return a
```

I did this so as to easily populate a table cell somewhere on my site.  But this isn't something that I want shown this way elsewhere.

So in my view I tried to show only the contents of self.name by trying to delete everything else.

```
allObj = LeadContact.objects.all()
for b in allObj:
  b.name = b.name[0:b.name.find('<br>')]
```

I was presented with the error:

```
Exception Value: 'ClientContact' object has no attribute 'find'
```

My question is two fold, what sort of operations can I perform on objects and how might I best solve this problem?

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: So, you used your normal string method (which is used 99% of the time you want a string) to do something for a corner case, and now you're trying to reprocess away the change you made to fix it for the 99% again. Do you see why this approach is confusing? Use `__str__` for whatever you want _not_ in that table, and make some `to_table_cell` method or some such for that one time.

Comment: @utkbansal I have a table that populate's via one model (let's call it 'A') and it has a foreign key from model (B).  And I want to be able to interact with most of the content in model (B) i.e. self.name, self.phone, self.email throughout my site but I want to be able to loop through the content in model A to create the table that I already have.

Comment: Generating html in your views is not a good idea. You may want to make a separate method for it and call it in your templates.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have the error because your `b.name` is an object of `ClientContact`, so you cannot use `find` to it. You should do your `str(self.name)` first and apply `find` on it.

However, I don't think altering the output in `views.py` is handy. The quick way is to move the body of your current `__str__` method to another method in the class(call it something like `html_display`) and call that method from your template.

Further more, it's not good practice to return html from views.py to the template, you should separate the backend code from frontend code as much as possible. So I would suggest creating a django template tag/filter for it.

Comment: "the quick way is to move the body of your __str__ method to another method in the class(call it something like html_display) and call that method from your template."
Could you give an example of what you mean by this?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve your problem would be to create a new method to generate the html code(not the `__str__` one) and call it in the templates.

Leave the `__str__` to the basic one -

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

So you could do something like -

```
def make_html(self): 
    a = str(self.name) +'<br>' + str(self.phone)+'<br>'+ str(self.email)
    return a
```

And then call this method in your templates.